# WPF - Horizontal align in items container item template

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, itemscontrol

I need to create List View, which would be displaying like data-grid. (Data will be displaying in columns).

Also needs to perform it without `GridView`, definitely without column names on top. My current code:

```
                 <Rectangle  Width="18" Margin="6,2,0,2"
                        Height="14" Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" >
                     <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                          <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_nfc}" />
                     </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                      <Rectangle.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                             <Style.Triggers>
                                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                      Mode=FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                         Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                 </DataTrigger>
                             </Style.Triggers>
                         </Style>
                  </Rectangle.Style>
                 </Rectangle>

                 <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Grid.Column="2">
                       Album Title
                 </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

That's what I have for now -

[image]

But I need to place "Album Title" from previous page like names there -

[image]

**But without column names on top.**

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like? Sounds like you probably have several options to accomplish it but I'm having trouble visualizing what you want from your description.

Comment: I need to display Album title, which on the last screen claved to the song name linke a column, started from one line.

Comment: Can you give a visual example? I'm still not sure if you mean you would like the title in a column and the artist in a column or what? I interpret "claved" as a pair of sticks or blocks so I'm not quite understanding what you mean amigo.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope you help me. If there - likes from me and mark as correct answer without fail. :)